# HttpURLConnectoin POST data not sent

Tags: android, http-post, httpurlconnection

I want to send json data to my webserver from an Android App. Therefore I wrote the following method:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String id = Configuration.getUserId();
        String date = sdf.format( new Date() );
        String type = "message";
        String message = params[0];

        try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put( "id", id);
            json.put( "date", date );
            json.put( "type", type );
            json.put( "message", message );

            byte[] postData = URLEncoder.encode( json.toString(), "UTF-8" ).getBytes();

            URL url = new URL( Configuration.loggingURL );
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream ( conn.getOutputStream () );
            out.write(postData);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("RemoteLogging","Data sent.");

        return null;
    }
```

On the server side I have something like this:

```
public class LoggingServlet extends HttpServlet {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Override
    public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("LoggingServlet: doPost got called");
```

However, this does not work, no data arrives at my server. The doPost method even does not get called (i.e. I see nothing in the logs of my tomcat server). I additionally have an iPhone app that successfully sends the data to my server and I tested the Configuration.loggingURL in the browser such that I can be sure that it is the correct url to call.

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I just checked with Wireshark that there is no outgoing traffic from the Android app (run in the simulator). So nothing is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember stumbling upon this issue in the past. Culprit as far as I remember was connections that were kept alive.

Try setting `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");` and then making the request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false"); above of URL url = new URL( Configuration.loggingURL ); but it has no effect.

Comment: Hm, try setting that before everything, e.g. in `Application.onCreate()`. If doesn't work, probably not this case.. Anyway, `HttpUrlConnection` was quite buggy and unreliable in <=2.3, Apache's `HttpClient` would be better if targeting older devices. I'd use come library in your case though, [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) or [Android AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http)

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve it, but do not really understand why it is working now:

I replaced

```
byte[] postData = URLEncoder.encode( json.toString(), "UTF-8" ).getBytes();

        URL url = new URL( Configuration.loggingURL );
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream ( conn.getOutputStream () );
        out.write(postData);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        conn.disconnect();
```

with the following code:

```
URL url = new URL( Configuration.loggingURL );
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString( json.toString().length() ));
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode( json.toString().length() );
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.connect();

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            writer.write( json.toString() );
            writer.flush();
            conn.disconnect();
```

This works fine.